# CQL in ndepend and cppdepend to see changes in metrics across revisions

Tags: ndepend, cql, cqlinq

CQL makes it easy to find methods where [CodeWasChanged](http://www.cppdepend.com/CQL.htm#_Toc200950458) but I also need to compare the metrics - I want to find modified code and see if it has improved or not.

I'm evaluating [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com) and [cppdepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) for a mixed code base. I'm very impressed with both, especially how well cppdepend seems to cope with our legacy and modern c++.

If I can work out how to do this then I can do everything I need within CQL but otherwise have to do something like combine reports externally. So I'd appreciate tips on automating and comparing report generation from CQL as a fallback. Obviously I would be happier using CQL inside VisualCppDepend or VisualNDepend so I can see the results of queries in the metric view. The live exploration of results is the **big deal** with these tools, compared to others.

The comments on CodeWasChanged and other clauses like [IsInOlderBuild](http://www.cppdepend.com/CQL.htm#_IsInOlderBuild_ANTMF) say *forces CQL to be run against the older build* which suggests you can't have a query work across revisions.

The kind of query I'd like is something like, imagining syntax:

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE CodeWasChanged and MethodCe > 10
```

generalised to work across versions

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE CodeWasChanged and MethodCe > 10 and BaseMethodCe < 10
```

or maybe

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE CodeWasChanged and MethodCe > 10 and Older(MethodCe < 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andy, with [CQLinq (Code Query and Rule over LINQ)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) see trending in code metrics is possible and hopefully easy to achieve. See for example the default code rule [Avoid making complex methods even more complex (Source CC)](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex_%28Source_CC%29.html):

```
// <Name>Avoid making complex methods even more complex (Source CC)</Name>
// To visualize changes in code, right-click a matched method and select:
//  - Compare older and newer versions of source file
//  - Compare older and newer versions disassembled with Reflector

warnif count > 0 
from m in JustMyCode.Methods where
 !m.IsAbstract &&
  m.IsPresentInBothBuilds() &&
  m.CodeWasChanged()

let oldCC = m.OlderVersion().CyclomaticComplexity
where oldCC > 6 && m.CyclomaticComplexity > oldCC 

select new { m,
    oldCC ,
    newCC = m.CyclomaticComplexity ,
    oldLoc = m.OlderVersion().NbLinesOfCode,
    newLoc = m.NbLinesOfCode,
}
```

We'd advise to browse related default code rules in the default group: **Code Quality Regression**